# Why is sqlsrv_fetch_array() returning null?

Tags: php, sql-server, null, sqlsrv

I am trying to make a very simple query to a SQL database using PHP, but no matter what I do, it seems it can't pull any proper results. The following is the code I have written:

```
$loDate = '2013-10-01';
$hiDate = '2015-01-01';
$queryStr = "select TimeCol from dbo.SUBPUMP where TimeCol between " . $loDate . " and " . $hiDate;
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conInfo);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $queryStr);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    // This never prints.
    echo "row:<br>"; var_dump($row); echo "<br><br>";
}

echo "<br><br><br>";

// Prints "conInfo: resource(2) of type (SQL Server Connection)"
echo "conn: "; var_dump($conn); echo "<br><br>";

// Prints "result: resource(3) of type (SQL Server Statement)"
echo "result: "; var_dump($result); echo "<br><br>";

// Prints "row: NULL"
echo "row: "; var_dump($row); echo "<br><br>";
```

What I am confused on is how it can establish a proper connection to the database.

Since `$conn` and `$result` do not print any errors, but yet do not seem to actually fetch any data for me.

So far, my best guess is that since I am attempting to grab the data from a database through a VPN, and thus might only have a tenuous connection, that the `sqlsrv_connect()` will attempt to try many times to connect to the database until it receives a single good connection. While the `sqlsrv_query()` will only attempt this once, and thus fails to gather any data.

Does anyone else have any ideas as to what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even your result is equal to null, $result returns this

> ```
> // Prints "result: resource(.) of type (SQL Server Statement)"
> echo "result: "; var_dump($result); echo "<br><br>";
> ```

Your query may returns null, because of your date format. Did you try this query without dates

> $queryStr = "select TimeCol from dbo.SUBPUMP";

Comment: Interestingly, if I remove the entire WHERE clause of the query and modify it slightly so that it appears as "select top 10 TimeCol from dbo.SUBPUMP" so that I forgo the use of the timestamps, it actually prints the results properly - so now I have narrowed the issue down to how PHP wants to interpret my date-like strings. Unfortunately this is an issue, because the next step I will be taking will be interpreting user input and date ranges and figuring those into my query strings, so I will need this working at somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php), for `sqlsrv_fetch_array`, states:

> Returns an array on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs.

A `NULL` result can therefore only mean that there are **0 results** from your query. So  `while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))` will never loop.

You could handle this with a conditional check with `sqlsrv_has_rows()`. This returns a boolean `true` if there are more than 0 rows.

For example:

```
if (sqlsrv_has_rows($result)) {
  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "row:<br>"; var_dump($row); echo "<br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "<br/>No Results were found."; 
}
```

Comment: I figured as such. However, then this means that my sqlsrv_query() method is returning nothing, but yet the sqlsrv_connect() method has established connection. The query is syntactically correct since I can copy-paste it into my MS SQL Server Management Studio and run it fine.

Comment: It will *run* fine (as in no errors) - However there are *no results* - Which is not actually an error (hence `NULL` rather than `false`)

Comment: @imprisoned243 what results are you getting for the same query in MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: But there are results I receive when I make the same query in my MS SQL Server Management Studio. So it seems something is not working, since it is not grabbing the proper data that I know exists. The results I get in the Management Studio are 569 rows of date-time stamps.

Comment: @imprisoned243 Id the SQL generated identical? Might be worth `var_dump($queryStr)` to see the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are referring to date column, try setting "ReturnDatesAsStrings" option in connection option(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167.aspx).

**Sample connection:-**

```
$connection['UID'] = $username;
$connection['PWD'] = $password;
$connection['Database'] = $database_name;
$connection['ReturnDatesAsStrings'] = true;
$connection['ConnectionPooling'] = false;
$connection['CharacterSet'] = 'UTF-8';

if (!empty($port)) {
  $hostname = $hostname.', '.$port;
}

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, $connection);
```

Also try setting cursor type to "SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC" in sql_query function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487160.aspx)

**Sample Query:-**

```
$result_id = sqlsrv_query($conn, $queryStr, null, array(
                'Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC,
                'SendStreamParamsAtExec'=> true
            ));


while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result_id)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised this has gone so long without an answer. The problem here is very simple: The dates don't have single quotes around them.

```
$loDate = '2013-10-01';
$hiDate = '2015-01-01';
$queryStr = "select TimeCol from dbo.SUBPUMP where TimeCol between '" . $loDate . "' and '" . $hiDate . "'";
```

SQL Server requires date strings to be quoted to interpret them as dates.

Also, probably worth noting that you should be using a prepared statement. That is safer and doesn't require you to quote your string.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer, but I was having he same problem with it today.

Turns out I was using an old version of PHP. Updating to a newer version fixed this for me. 
In my case it was going from version 5.6 to 7.2.